# Playframework NoSuchMethodError

Tags: scala, nosuchmethoderror, playframework-2.1, slick

I've got a problem when trying to use Slick... I've followed exactly [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/getting-started-play-21-scala) article at first. Everything is good until I add Bars.ddl.create in Global.scala. At this point it launches the excpetion bellow.

```
NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$ArrowAssoc$.extension$$minus$greater(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/Tuple2;
```

I suppose it's due to the method "def * = ..." but I can't change anything.

I've tried an sbt-reboot to as I've seen on a forum but it wouldn't change.

I have Scala-2.10.0, Play-2.1.0

Do you know what's the problem? (And eventually how to solve it =D)

Thanks

Comment: could you share the code that is causing this?

Comment: Yes, we'll need more code to help you.

Comment: This is usually a symptom of compiling with one version of scala-library and running with another.